# How to solve the black screen problem on boot of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, updates

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 using the Software Updater, vbut after the reboot, the boot is stuck at a black screen with some text and each line starting with a  green [OK]. I don't want to clean install the OS again as I have some important files on the hard drive.

Here is an image of the black screen.

[image]

Comment: those "OK" msgs are common. at this screen boot is struck? have you tried to force shut down and restart the system? is it ubuntu 17.10 alone or Dual booting? try to take the back up first by entering into live session with bootable usb of 17.10 or 18.04.

Comment: Yes, Boot stucks at the black screen in the image. I have tried both force shut down and restart but no positive results. And it is a dual boot with windows 10

Comment: Do you have bootable USB of any Ubuntu? U said you have important file in Ubuntu. Can you enter live session and take the backup of that file first. Later in command line try `sudo apt-get update` your data is in / folder or in Ntfs partition? If you have Ubuntu 17 installed in separate partition you can format it and try fresh installation.

Comment: i have faced the same problem when i upgraded 17.04 to 17.10 from software updater. i took the back up and freshly installed 17.10 in the same partition. Its a quick way. But in your case you dont want to reinstall OS. So make a bootable USB Ubuntu 18.04 enter live session and from there you will have options. First take the Back up of your Important File from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you reboot? Pressing ESC or SHIFT while Grub booting, there must come some menu options

choose recovery mode and then dpkg

or normaly you can use an install-stick an choose repair option.

but be carefull, you give less information. So its a quick tip.

Comment: The same screen appears when I reboot.